# Check SMTP over SSL

Tags: email, ssl, smtp

I need to get a look at how my SSL mailserver plays with others; for non-SSL this is easy to do with (e.g.) `telnet`. Is there a bonified SSL/TLS client that can be used the same way?

Comment: Besides your other posted solution it's also possible [using openssl s_client](https://qmail.jms1.net/test-auth.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, `gnutls-cli`, but there are a few minor tricks required to get it to work.

```
gnutls-cli --crlf foobar.com -p 465
```

Some online tutorials for this use `-s foobar.com`.  This does not seem to be necessary, although if the above fails you could try it.  **If you use `-s`** you will have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (to send EOF) afterward in order to initiate the TLS session.

`--crlf` is required because the (E)SMTP protocol uses a DOS style carriage return, line feed to end lines.  Without this the server will not respond.

`-p` is for port, and here I've used the fairly standard 465 for SMTP over SSL.

You should see some (copious) output regarding the server's certificate ending with:

```
- Handshake was completed

- Simple Client Mode:
```

And hopefully right after that the first statement from the server:

```
220 mailserver1.foobar.com ESMTP
```

You can now do [whatever it was](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) you were thinking of doing with telnet; since in this case it is **ESMTP** we use `EHLO` instead of `HELO`

```
EHLO fake.org
```

The server should reply with a list of characteristics/capabilities, or perhaps if very vigilant, say sorry, "fake.org" appears to be a lie ;)